# AsyncPipe not working when interval is returned by a function

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

So I'm messing up a little bit with Observers and I can't understand why methods that returns `interval` can't display the observers data using the [`AsyncPipe`](https://angular.io/guide/observables-in-angular#async-pipe)

**component.ts**

```
import {interval} from "rxjs";

export class CalendarComponent implements OnInit {
  interval: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.interval = interval(1000);
  }

  myInterval() {
    return interval(1000);
  }
}
```

**component.html**

```
INTERVAL : {{interval | async}} //Displays the interval incrementing each second
FUNCTION : {{myInterval() | async}} //Not working
```

Comment: It's because you didn't call the `myInterval` function. Unless it's a getter or a variable, you need the necessary parenthesis after the function name to call the function.

Comment: Woops, forgot to add them in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time angular refreshes page by change detector, it checks values/references of bound objects and if there is new one, algorithm puts new values into view. `myInterval()` method gives reference for new object on every change detection tick. Probable angular has trouble in loading your view. `this.interval` is all the time same object, so its loaded only once to session cache.

Similar situation is when you would put a PromiseLike type into view like this:

```
getPromisValue() {
    return Promise.resolve("anything");
}

<p>{{getPromiseValue() | async}}</p>
```

its all the time the same value but new promise reference so view will have a trouble to load it.

To track such situations, good practise is to inject `ngZone` in `app.component.ts` and log `onStable` observable.

```
constructor(
    private zone: NgZone
  ) {
    this.zone.onStable.asObservable().subscribe(() => console.log("onStable"));
  }
```

As angular doc says https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone#onStable it:

> Notifies when the last onMicrotaskEmpty has run and there are no more microtasks, which implies we are about to relinquish VM turn. This event gets called just once.

So if you will do something wrong, you will see in console that log occurs too many times. Disable this on production.

Comment: This is technically incorrect. Angular does not track the return values from functions. The problem here is that Angular has *no clue* if a function has *any* side effects. So when the compiler converts a template expression to JavaScript and it sees a function it marks the expression as **impure**. So it will evaluate the expression every render pass. Pipes are the only functions you can use in a template that can be marked as *pure*. This is why we have pipes.

Answer (score 3):

If you try

```js
myInterval() {
    console.log('here');
    return interval(1000);
}
```

you will notice that this function is getting called each 1s. That will give you new object every time (`return interval(1000)`), hence using just reference is working.

**Why this is happening ?** (With inputs from @C_Ogoo)

As you are returning interval of 1s, after that the change detection cycle kicks in as you have used interpolation here. Due to this the function gets called again and resulting in new interval every time.

Comment: I think this is also to do with the change detection cycle. So everytime change detection is ran, the function `myInterval` will be called and thus returning a new `interval`

Comment: Exactly. I was just going through the documentation. I ll update the answer.

Comment: @C_Ogoo `myInterval() | async` the async pipe calls `markForCheck()` when a value is emitted. So the pipe itself is triggering the change detection on the view, and then a new observable is created and async starts over.

Answer (score 2):

It is invoked and works exactly as you would expect.

the problem is, since its a function, it will constantly get evaluated, and return a new interval reference on each change detection cycle.

change your function's:return value to

`return interval(1).pipe(tap(n => console.log(n)))`

it will make things much clearer